# Successful preflight, but cancelled responses with authorization headers

Tags: express, cors, http-headers, authorization, http2

I'm working on an Ionic application that is communicating with an express server. Things were working fine until this last publish cycle. Upon deployment, half of our API calls stopped functioning correctly on our live server.

I've narrowed down the issue to our requests that contain an Authorization header. All other requests that don't need that Auth header are working fine, but ones that have an auth return a 204 on the prefilght options check, but then the actual request is canceled. Console gives a `0 -  {"isTrusted":true}` in Firefox and `net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` on Chrome. The actual requests are not even hitting the server that I can tell, and the response is just an empty response object with status code: 0.

So I'm not sure where to go from here, I've been reading about CORS issues but we haven't changed any headers or configuration recently.

Also, what is crazy is our testing build on iPhone 5 is working fine, but on desktop web browsers and Android it's failing. Could be an older version of Safari Mobile?

Here is an example GET request that is failing with the auth header.

```
PREFLIGHT REQUEST:
Host: app.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: app-api-key,authorization
Origin: http://localhost:8100
Connection: keep-alive

PREFLIGHT RESPONSE:
server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
date: Sat, 03 Mar 2018 06:14:39 GMT
x-dns-prefetch-control: off
x-download-options: noopen
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:8100
vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
access-control-allow-headers: app-api-key,authorization
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN, SAMEORIGIN
x-content-type-options: nosniff, nosniff
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2

GET REQUEST HEADERS:
Accept  application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
app-api-key: fakeapikeyhere
Authorization: JWT fakejwtauthtokenhere
Connection: keep-alive
Host: app.example.com
Origin: http://localhost:8100
Referer: http://localhost:8100/?ionicpl…tp://localhost:8100/ionic-lab
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0
```

Answer (score 2):

HTTP/2 is quite strict about HTTP headers and will not allow requests when these are malformed. So it’s likely there is still a problem here, but HTTP/1.1 is just being a bit more lenient about it.

[This post](https://www.michalspacek.com/chrome-err_spdy_protocol_error-and-an-invalid-http-header) gives good information on how to debug any HTTP Header issues by using the chrome://net-internals/#events page in Chrome and then looking at the HTTP2_SESSION. Though that is more intended for bad receiving of headers, whereas your problem looks to be in sending that last request.

There definitely seems to be something up with your headers though:

```
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN, SAMEORIGIN
x-content-type-options: nosniff, nosniff
```

Why are these values repeated?

```
GET REQUEST HEADERS:
Accept  application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
```

Why do these values not have a colon after the header name?

Not sure if both of those are typos or copy/paste errors but they look a bit suspect as they are now.

Additionally, under HTTP/2 all header names should be lowercase, though most browsers convert this automatically for you. Header values can be upper, lower or mixed case.

Hopefully that gives you a bit more to go on to investigate further.

Comment: +1 These are good points. I'm going to investigate some of them. I think the duplication is caused by using both helmet and cors npm packages. Not sure about the semi colons missing.

Comment: Duplicate headers won’t generally cause a problem but odd. Colons (not semi-colons) missing WILL cause problems in HTTP/2.

Answer (score 0):

So I have half resolved this. This ended up actually being some sort of HTTP/2.0 issue. I think something got updated or enabled when my Digital Ocean server was restarted recently. Certain browsers that didn't support HTTP/2.0 were working while others were not. I'm not entirely sure why my calls don't work on HTTP/2.0 but that's a separate question.

If you're looking to debug if this is your issue you can try to run chrome and disable http2 and see if it begins working. From the chrome directory run:

```
./chrome.exe --disable-http2
```

My specific situation was resolved by removing http2 from my NGINX config.

Running:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

And editing the below:

```
# SSL Config
listen 443 ssl http2 default_server; # <- Removed the http2
listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server; # <- Removed the http2
```

And then restarting it

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```